# Add a button in a Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a simple form in which the user is specifying the name of a (Bloomberg)Ticker. In a second field the user is entering an address of a webpage. Of course, she/he can manually correct it but I would like to offer him/her a button such that the app suggests the name of the page based on the content of first Ticker field, e.g. the user enters "CARMPAT FP Equity" and then the app suggests correctly 
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CARMPAT:FP

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm, ValidationError
from pybloomberg.bloomberg import valid_ticker

from .models import Symbol


class SymbolAdminForm(ModelForm):

    # Have a button next to address field...

    class Meta:
        model = Symbol
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        ticker = cleaned_data.get('bloomberg_symbol')
        return cleaned_data

    def react(self):
        # extract the content for the bloomberg_symbol field
        address = ...
        # manipulate the content for the address field
        self.... = address
```

Comment: I should emphasize that I have the functionality to map tickers to suggestions in place already...

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't you use Javascript to accomplish this? It sounds a bit like "autocomplete" to me.

Comment: Well, I try to avoid going down the jQuery and Javascript route for now. I am playing currently html templates. Note that I do not want any automated update in case the user is changing the symbol/ticker.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the suggestion to be applied automatically after the form is posted, you can move your logic to the clean() method and you will need to allow the address field to be empty.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    ticker = cleaned_data.get('bloomberg_symbol')
    cleaned_data['address'] = ticker_name_to_address()
    return cleaned_data
```

If you want the suggestion to be displayed to the users when they enter the name, you will have no choice but to use JavaScript.

Comment: Sure, that's an option but this would overwrite an existing state if there is one. I really want an extra button and the suggestion shall only have impact if the user is clicking the button